# Variables emptying or erasing on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, xcode, variables, tableview

For some reason, I can't access any of my variables after the first IF Statement in the following code. For instance, if index path is [0,0], then the variable phoneText spits out a phone number. But if its [1,0] or [2,0], I get a "null" return. Why is my variable being erased?

The following function in mapviewcontroller.m sets the values. I do actually have an error here that says "instance method setDetails not found".

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    //this determines what kind of item was selected
    if ([control isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

        NSLog(@"Trying to load VenueIdentifier...");

        FinderAnnotation *clicked = view.annotation;      

        FinderViewController *fvi = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FinderDetail"];

        NSString* latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",clicked.coordinate.latitude];
        NSString* longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",clicked.coordinate.longitude];

        NSLog(@"lat: %@",latitude);
        NSLog(@"lon: %@",longitude);

        [fvi setDetails:clicked.title phone:clicked.phone address:clicked.address beersavailable:clicked.beersavailable latitude:latitude longitude:longitude];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:fvi animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Then my finderdetail.h creates these variables:

```
@interface FinderDetail : UITableViewController{

    UITableViewCell *phone;
    UITableViewCell *address;
    UITableViewCell *directions;
    UILabel *venueLabel;

    NSString *phoneText;
    NSString *addressText;
    NSString *venueText;
    NSString *beersavailable;

    NSString *latitudeText;
    NSString *longitudeText;
    }

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *phone;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *directions;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *venueLabel;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *phoneText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *addressText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *venueText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *beersavailble;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *latitudeText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *longitudeText;


@end
```

Lastly, finderdetail.m grabs these values, assigns them to the variables, and spits them into the table:

```
@implementation FinderDetail

@synthesize venueLabel, phone, address, directions;
@synthesize phoneText, addressText, venueText, beersavailble, latitudeText, longitudeText;
NSString *notlisted;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setDetails:(NSString *)v phone:(NSString *)p address:(NSString *)a beersavailable:(NSString *)ba latitude:(NSString *)lat longitude:(NSString *)lon
{
    NSLog(@"venue: %@",v);
    NSLog(@"phone: %@",p);
    NSLog(@"address: %@",a);
    NSLog(@"beersavailable: %@",ba);
    NSLog(@"%@",lat);
    NSLog(@"%@",lon);

    latitudeText = lat;
    longitudeText = lon;  
    phoneText = p;
    addressText = a;
    venueText = v;
    beersavailble = ba;


    NSLog(@"%@", latitudeText);
    NSLog(@"%@", longitudeText);


    notlisted = @"Not Listed";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Latitude: %@", latitudeText);
    NSLog(@"Longitude: %@", longitudeText);


    phone.detailTextLabel.text = phoneText;
    address.detailTextLabel.text = addressText;
    self.venueLabel.text = venueText;

    if(phoneText == nil){
        phone.detailTextLabel.text = notlisted;
    }

    if(addressText == nil){
        address.detailTextLabel.text = notlisted;
    }

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if(section ==0)
        return 1;
    else
    if(section ==1)
        return 1;
    else
    if(section ==2)
        return 1;
    else
    return 0;
}
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);

        if((indexPath.section==0) && (indexPath.row ==0))
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",phoneText);
        }

        if((indexPath.section==1) && (indexPath.row ==0))
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",addressText);
        }

        if((indexPath.section==2) && (indexPath.row ==0))
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",latitudeText);
            NSLog(@"%@",longitudeText);
        }
    }
```

The initial phoneText will display in an NSLog, but the addressText and latitudeText and longitudeText return null. I can put phoneText in one of those lower if statements and it too returns null. Thanks!!!

Comment: is `phoneText` being modified / set on a different thread (and could this be happening at the same time)?  are you using ARC? If not, is `phoneText` retained or autoreleased?

Comment: Please provide more information (code) about `phoneText`

Comment: I created phoneText in the headerfile (detailviewcontroller.h) as an NSString *phoneText, I set the properties to (nonatomic, retain), and then synthesize it in the m file, of which the code above is in (detailviewcontroller.m).

phoneText is set by a void method called setDetails. On a view controller that loads a map (mapcontrollerview), setdetails is called and given values for many different variables (phone, address, latitude, longitude, etc), then pushes the detailviewcontroller onto the navigation stack where a user can see detailed attributes about the map annotation.

Comment: WHile that is a convincing argument the fact remains that there is a code error so there is something that is escaping your argument. The only way you can get help is to show more code. You can edit your question to add that.

Comment: Thanks @CocoaFu. I added code. Just to point out clearly, the only time the variables return null is in those last to if statements. Any variable.

Comment: @user1080937 The additional code provided what was needed to find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually using your `@property` when you are doing the following:

```
latitudeText = lat;
longitudeText = lon;  
phoneText = p;
addressText = a;
venueText = v;
beersavailble = ba;
```

Also, you are leaking memory every time those assignments are performed after the initial time (when they were still `nil`).

What you really want is:

```
self.latitudeText = lat;
self.longitudeText = lon;  
self.phoneText = p;
self.addressText = a;
self.venueText = v;
self.beersavailble = ba;
```

Also, with a `NSString` (also `NSData`, `NSSet`, etc.) `@property`, it is better to define them as a `copy`, since it would be perfectly valid to pass in a `NSMutableString` instead (since it is a subclass of `NSString`), which then the contents could be altered externally of this object:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *phoneText;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *addressText;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *venueText;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *beersavailble;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *latitudeText;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *longitudeText;
```

Finally, the fact that you get `(NULL)` outputted by `NSLog` suggests the ivars are getting set to nil (and most likely released), and you are using ARC (*Automatic Reference Counting*), instead of manual retain/release/autorelease.

Answer (score 1):

In `setDetails` you need to use the properties in order to retain the objects and release previous objects. Assigning directly to the ivars subverts the properties setters/getters and the memory management they provide is lost. Basically if properties are defined use them every time.

Since the objects are not being retained their memory can be reused and unpredictable results can occur such as the values becoming nil.

One way to find such problems is to turn on NSZombies in the simulator runs. I do this occasionally even when I am not having problems just as a check.

To fix the problem rewrite `setDetails` as:

```
-(void)setDetails:(NSString *)v phone:(NSString *)p address:(NSString *)a beersavailable:(NSString *)ba latitude:(NSString *)lat longitude:(NSString *)lon
{
    self.latitudeText = lat;
    self.longitudeText = lon;  
    self.phoneText = p;
    self.addressText = a;
    self.venueText = v;
    self.beersavailble = ba;

    self.notlisted = @"Not Listed";
}
```

One way to insure that properties are not inadvertently not used is to define the ivars with a slightly different name than the properties. The synthesize statement supports this. Here is how:
in the `@interface`:

```
NSString *_latitudeText;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *latitudeText;
```

in the `@implementation`

```
@synthesize latitudeText = _latitudeText;
```

Comment: Thanks @gschandler. That made it work. Is there a problem with using ARC? Some of my code only works when I use ARC, do I need to change it to work without it?

Comment: @user1080937 There is no problem with ARC, use it if possible.